# Sumar valores y traerlos con un inner join

Tags: mysqli

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta sql para generar un informe y necesite que de una misma tabla me traiga diferentes validaciones, Cuento con una tabla cotizaciones y una tabla pagos ocupo traer una sumatoria por cada id_cotizaciones en donde la forma de pago es A y la otra B, ademas a esto tengo una fecha de seña que es el primer pago que se realizo de dicha cotizacion. Pongo un ejemplo del query que estoy realizando.

| id_coti |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

| id_pago | id_coti | valor | f_pago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | pagoa |
| 2 | 1 | 50 | pagoa |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | pagob |
| 4 | 1 | 40 | pagob |

Estas son las tablas que tengo y necesito que traiga la suma donde f_pago= pagoa y donde f_pago=pagob donde id_coti=1

Este un ejemplo del query que realizo y lo que ocupo es que cobrosa.valor me lo traiga sumado para cada cotizaciones.id:

```
SELECT cotizaciones.id, nameusua.nombre, 
concat_ws(' ', clientes.nombres, clientes.apellidos) as nombre_cli, cotizaciones.tipo_producto, 
((cotizaciones.subtotal*cotizaciones.forma_pagoa)+(cotizaciones.subtotal*cotizaciones.iva)) Importe_Total,
 ((cotizaciones.subtotal*cotizaciones.forma_pagob)+(cotizaciones.subtotal*cotizaciones.iva_b)) Complemento,
 pagos_coti.fecha_pago, 
cobrosa.valor
FROM clientes
        INNER JOIN cotizaciones ON clientes.id = cotizaciones.id_contacto 
        INNER JOIN usuarios as nameusua ON cotizaciones.asesor = nameusua.id 
        INNER JOIN usuarios as nameasis ON cotizaciones.asistente = nameasis.id 
        INNER JOIN pagos as cobrosa ON (cotizaciones.id = cobrosa.id_cotizacion) AND (cobrosa.formas_pago = 'pagoa')
        JOIN (SELECT pagos.id_cotizacion, MIN(pagos.fecha_pago) AS fecha_pago FROM pagos WHERE pagos.observacion != 'ANULADO' GROUP BY pagos.id_cotizacion HAVING SUM(pagos.valor)>0) pagos_coti ON cotizaciones.id = pagos_coti.id_cotizacion
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Tienes algún ejemplo del query que has intentado hacer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @AbrahamChan acabe de editar la pregunta con un query que tengo funcional, mas no me suma la cantidad de cobroa.valor dependiendo de cada id_cotizacion

Comment: Pero tu query no tiene nada pero nada que ver con tu ejemplo...

Comment: @CristianGuzman veo que tienes un join con `pagos as cobrosa` y además tiene un subquery igual hacia pagos como `pagos_coti`, ¿por que estás juntando dos veces la misma tabla pagos si con el subquery puedes enviar el resultado de la suma de valor con la función de agregación que usas?

Comment: @AbrahamChan debido en que en una necesito que me lo traiga donde formas_pago = 'pagoa' y el otro sin dicha validacion

Comment: A lo que voy es que, como falta sumar los valores, podrías usar el mismo camino para hacer la suma `INNER JOIN (SELECT pagos.id_cotizacion, SUM(pagos.valor) AS Valor FROM pagos WHERE pagos.formas_pago = 'pagoa' 
GROUP BY pagos.id_cotizacion) AS cobrosa ON cotizaciones.id = cobrosa.id_cotizacion ` pero me salta un poco el hecho de tener el subquery muy similar

Comment: @AbrahamChan soy un poco inexperto en el tema de generar consultas sql por eso mismo trato de solucionarlo recursivamente en lo que encuentro una manera mas optima de realizarlo y traer el mismo resultado, no se si conoces una forma mejor de realizar la consulta correctamente